# Strange behavior of JAVA : getSubimage() function

Tags: java, image

**Hello there,**

I am running the following code to make a screenshot of my JPanel.

```
private void makePanelImage(Component panel, String saveAs) {
    Dimension size = panel.getSize();
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // CROP
     // BufferedImage cropped = image.getSubimage(9, 31, 2459, 3467);
     BufferedImage cropped = image.getSubimage(1800, 2000, 500, 700);

    Graphics2D g2 = cropped.createGraphics();
    panel.paint(g2);
    saveAs = saveAs + ".png";
    try {
        ImageIO.write(cropped, "png", new File(saveAs));
        System.out.println("Image Saved: " + saveAs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problematic part is:

```
BufferedImage cropped = image.getSubimage(1800, 2000, 500, 700);
```

No matter what I set X and Y to - it ALWAYS is taken as ignored. As it would be 0 and 0. And I have no idea why? Has anyone encountered this before? The second part - width and height do have effect on the image, I can make it smaller as much as I want - which is nice. But the top left "beginning" of the raster WONT move.

Is this a bug?

Note: What is funny though, the moment I set it to OFFSET + WIDTH > ORIGINAL I get an error - which is logical but still It wont get "moved"

Am I missing here something please?

Comment: Where are you actually populating the image? We see you creating a new `BufferedImage`, and then creating a subimage of it... it would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hello Jon, thank you for your reply. I dont really understand what you mean by populating. The idea is that this method should be applicable on any JPanel and with a JPanel sent it should provide a sent filename. I dont think it can get more minimal?

Comment: It works fine when I run it...

Comment: What you've got isn't complete. We can't run it and see the problem. More importantly, it's still not obvious what you're trying to achieve. I see now that you're painting onto the cropped version... so you're not so much trying to crop an existing image as paint onto a *part* of a larger image? (It helps if you describe what you're trying to do...)

Comment: Than it has to be some bug with my java? Latest JAVA and JRE installed yesterday :(

Comment: Well the produced "screenshot" without cropping produces and image that contains parts that I am not interested into. So I try to crop them away. Lets say 10 px from any side. But whatever I try - It only takes into account the second part (width and height) the 1st part - where the "top-left" corner should be "moved" is ignored on my build.

Comment: I'm testing with a blank panel though. You could still try to paint first and then crop, if you hadn't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
panel.paint(g2);
BufferedImage cropped = image.getSubimage(1800, 2000, 500, 700);
```

Comment: It works!!! Oh man thank you! But - well im no JAVA guru how can that be? I mean I dont get the point where I "crop" after I have painted it? But I have to admit I have no idea what .paint() does. For me it was something like "final step". Wow!